# Want to use join command only on second / inner for loop to have all authors in one cell

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, selenium-webdriver

[New Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe7HA.png)

[New Code for fetching authors role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LufiR.png)

[Old, Output I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0AY8.png)

I want to have list of authors in one cell, for that I am using .join() command.

A little into to my code and what I am trying to accomplish:

Main link is a list of 20 items and each item has a list of 4-5 authors. First I want to iterate over links and then over the each of its items to get list of authors in one cell of csv.

It's nightmare for me. I have spent days in figuring out the answer, hopefully someone will help and understand the problem. Ask for more information, thank you. Output is attached below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd    
driver = webdriver.Chrome()    
site = 'https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=chughtai&qid=WzdWh5nG8z'

driver.get(site)
driver.maximize_window()
authors = []
auth = []


main = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
for i in main:
    con = i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="authorName__container"]')
    for n in con:
        authors.append(n.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="authorName"]/span').text)
        one_cell = ', '.join(authors)
    auth.append(one_cell)

a = {'Author Names': one_cell}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
df.to_csv("only_names.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: Can you try this? `a = {'Author Names': [one_cell]}`, notice that now the value of your dict would be a list with a single element

Comment: @aaossa, sorry it didn't work.
I think changing should be made in for loops somewhere

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't you be using `auth` instead of `one_cell`? `a = {'Author Names': [auth]}`

Comment: I tried multiple ways but didn't work.  Solution from Raymond Kwok worked perfectly fine. I appreciate your help and time in reading and replying to my post. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that your problem is the author list does not reset to empty before you parse a new item. One way to reset it would be to move your `authors = []` from its current position to the line right after `for i in main:`. Then you will get a new, empty list for each item.

Another, non-critical, suggestion is to get your `one_cell = ', '.join(authors)` outside of the current, inner loop but still before `auth.append(one_cell)`. You only need to do both lines once for each `i`.

UPDATE:

To show my 2nd suggestion:

```
for i in main:
    authors = []
    con = i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="authorName__container"]')
    for n in con:
        authors.append(n.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="authorName"]/span').text)
    one_cell = ', '.join(authors)
    auth.append(one_cell)
```

Comment: Hey, Raymond,
Your first suggestion worked 100%. I got the required result. Second suggestion did not work but I am happy and appreciate your support. If you are in Canada, I will give you a treat for this. I am learning python own my own as I like coding a lot.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I am in Hong Kong. I updated my answer just in case I didn't describe it clearly. I usually check out unanswered questions here, and I hope to see you again in other questions, if any.

Comment: Yeah, second suggestion worked as well. Perfect.

I am new to stackoverflow. Is there a way to be in contact with someone like you every time someone needs help?. I mean, I was just curious.

Comment: Hey, Raymond
So far so good. Next I am trying to find following:
Each of the author containers has an author but not all all authors are translators and this is located in each container at   -- //span[@class="authorName greyText smallText role"]')  --
I have added a new list named as role in my code and loop through these containers to find which author has a role or not, like I was looping for author names but for this loop of role, I get errors. I am attaching new output and code block as picture. Please have a look, it is getting trickier here. Check website for details, Thank you.

Comment: @ Raymond,

if you can look at the following link, thank you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251220/its-tricky-can-you-solve-the-issue