# It's tricky, can you solve the issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, selenium, web-scraping

[Output I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nck7.png)

I want list of authors appended and in one cell, I can get that but not all authors have role mentioned in the website, so I want to have the author that has role with it's role. Out I want is attached above. See link. It's tricky for me, someone may be able to tackle this. Looking forward to the answers and I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
site = 'https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=chughtai&qid=WzdWh5nG8z'
driver.get(site)
driver.maximize_window()
roles = []
authors = []

main = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')

for i in main:
    role = []
    author = []
    con = i.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[@class="authorName__container"]')
    try:
        for n in con:
            auth = n.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="authorName"]/span').text
            rol = n.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="authorName greyText smallText role"]').text
            author.append(auth)
            if rol:
                role.append(rol)
                one = ', '.join(role)
                roles.append(auth + ' ' + rol)
            else:
                continue
        one_cell = ', '.join(author)
        authors.append(one_cell)
    except:
        pass

a = {'Author Name': authors,'Role': roles}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(a, orient='index')
df = df.transpose()
df.to_csv("only_roles.csv", index=False)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I can't run through your code to get all the books, so I modified it and please take whichever part that is useful from my version and bring to yours. My explanations in code's comments.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('...')
site = 'https://www.goodreads.com/search?q=chughtai&qid=WzdWh5nG8z'
driver.get(site)
driver.maximize_window()

data = [] # pandas can convert a list of dictionaries to a dataframe. Dictionary keys are column names.

for tr in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr'):
    # one tr for one book
    
    # I chose the following as check for a book because it worked for the webpage
    if tr.get_attribute('itemtype') != 'http://schema.org/Book':
        continue # Not a book
    
    temp = {'Author Names': [], 'Role': []}
        
    for con in tr.find_elements_by_class_name('authorName__container'):
        # one container for one author
        
        try:
            authorName = con.find_element_by_class_name('authorName').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
            temp['Author Names'].append(authorName)

            authorRole = con.find_element_by_class_name('role').text
            temp['Role'].append(f'{authorName} {authorRole}')

        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass # ignore this one

        except Exception as e:
            print(e) # print this one for inspection

    # convert lists to strings    
    data.append({k: ','.join(v) for k,v in temp.items()})
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

                                       Author Names  \
0                       Ismat Chughtai,M. Asaduddin   
1                                    Ismat Chughtai   
2   Muhammad Umar Memon,M. Asaduddin,Ismat Chughtai   
3                       Ismat Chughtai,Tahira Naqvi   
4                        Ismat Chughtai,Amar Shahid   
5       Ismat Chughtai,Tahira Naqvi,Syeda S. Hameed   
6                                    Ismat Chughtai   
7                                  Hephaestus Books   
8                       Ismat Chughtai,Tahira Naqvi   
9                                  Rakhshanda Jalil   
10                                   Ismat Chughtai   
11                                   Ismat Chughtai   
12                                   Ismat Chughtai   
13                              Azeem Baig Chughtai   
14                                   Ismat Chughtai   
15                                   Ismat Chughtai   
16                                   Ismat Chughtai   
17                                   Ismat Chughtai   
18                      Ismat Chughtai,Tahira Naqvi   
19                                 Hephaestus Books   

                                                 Role  
0                           M. Asaduddin (Translator)  
1                                                      
2   Muhammad Umar Memon (Translator),M. Asaduddin ...  
3                           Tahira Naqvi (Translator)  
4                              Amar Shahid (Compiler)  
5   Tahira Naqvi (Translator),Syeda S. Hameed (Tra...  
6                                                      
7                                                      
8                           Tahira Naqvi (Translator)  
9                           Rakhshanda Jalil (Editor)  
10                                                     
11                                                     
12                                                     
13                                                     
14                                                     
15                                                     
16                                                     
17                                                     
18                          Tahira Naqvi (Translator)  
19
```

Comment: Hi Raymond,
Once again this is awesome, Thank YOU.

I was more interested in learning the thought process for solving such issues, like getting name of author with their role and you have nailed it. It's simple and beautiful.

It took me hours and hundreds of tries but failed. I understand what's going on in your code but when it comes to myself writing something like this, I get stuck.

I am going to re-read your code multiple times until I fully grasp it. It fascinates me how powerful the logic and coding is. Once again thank you for your time, I appreciate it.

Have a great day.

Comment: Behind-the-sence. On side A of the gap you have a html, side B you want a dataframe. Building from B, my exp tells me what `pd.DataFrame` accepts so I am one step forward (`data = [] `) by being able to imagine how to organize my data with dict/list. From side A, actually I never used `selenium`, but other scraping libraries, and I have some exp in html syntax, and ***I have your sample code***. With these I checked out the full list of `find_element(s)_by_XXXXXXX` to see what options are on the table, and read the html code to look for some eye-catching keywords.

Comment: There I found `authorName__container`, `Author Names`, and `role`. You may wonder why `role` but in html syntax, if you specify your class like "wordA wordB wordC", your class has three class names, the key is they are space-separated. That's how I move steps forward from side B by writing those find_element codes. Finally I connect both sides by using `temp`, which is a dict of lists. I needed the flexibility of lists because I know there is an ***unknown*** number of authors, and it's only after parsing all authors in an item, I can join lists into strings.

Comment: With my example I explain how to build a DF from a list of dicts, you may checkout about the `data` argument in the doc https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html for other options, exercise to make them become your options as you need to bridge other gaps in future.

Comment: As for the `NoSuchElementException` thing, my practice is not to `pass` in the `expect` block because sometimes it can shield useful info from us. I found that the name of that exception by experimenting `con.find_element_by_class_name('this_never_works')`. And I am all aware that for the code inside `try`, if it produces such error, my official way of handling it is really to `pass`, here you see that my intention is not to silent it.

Comment: Although I also left `except Exception as e` here as the final catching of any other exceptions except for `NoSuchElementException`, it's actually useless because there should be no such other kinds. I am putting it there just for demo-ing my practice.

Comment: All good stuff here. I really appreciate your work and explanation.
I am new to stackoverflow and if I ever need any kind of help in future, I'll post here for sure. Thank you once again.

Comment: One more thing:

if I add couple more lists in temp lists, like this   temp = {'Author Names': [], 'Role': [], 'Book Name': [], 'Reviews': []} , then how will the final append and join command will look like?  data.append({k: ','.join(v) for k,v in temp.items()})

Comment: Never mind, I figured out the solution of my last comment.

Comment: I can get book name using following:

find_element_by_xpath('.//span[contains(@role, "heading")]').text

But I tried to use your code and made a little change in your code like adding extra list in temp and two extra lines of code try block to fetch book title, it didn't work, can you tell me the possible reason and point out the error in code snippet below:

    temp = {'Author Names': [], 'Role': [], 'Book Name': []}

    book_name = 
         con.find_element_by_class_name('bookTitle').find_element_by_tag_name('span').text
            
    temp['Book Name'].append(book_name)

Comment: In the code snippet, replace `con` with `tr`, and put that line right after `temp = {'Author.....`, instead of inside the inner for-loop. `'bookTitle'` does not exist in the scope of `con`, but `tr`. My description is under that assumption that you are using my version of code.

Comment: Perfect. it worked! I didn't even think about the scope of con for loop. See how a newbie's brain works, hahaha. Well, I really appreciate your answers and time. I have a quick question, do you work on freelancers.com? If not, if you start working there, you may earn a lot of projects. I used to work there and have better account but now I am busy in my job and main issue is I have no specific skill to sell there. You are too good at python, I can help you in setting a profile there. People like you are earning a lot over there. For last 4 years I haven't tried any bidding on projects.

Comment: Are you talking about freelancer.com? Never used that, but seems quite some competitions there - many bid for a project.

Comment: yeah, freelancer.com. I think many has good reviews but not all have good skills. freelancers there get projects and get it done from others and submit. I mean, if a person has time then it can be tried. It's true that because of competition winning a project is not easy there. I was just curious.